# 17 outside and I just have water, no anti freeze, am I OK?

Tags: engine, coolant, cold-weather

It's 17 degrees outside and I have no antifreeze in my car, will I be all right for just one night?

Comment: Assuming 17 F?  That's below the freezing point of water so you may have problems.  I guess the car is parked outside?

Comment: It also depends on when you turned the engine off - ie has it sat cold for 2 days or have you just turned it off and does it sit in the wind? all these factors can make a difference... It may help to cover it..

Comment: If you mean the radiator is empty ,you might get lucky with the pockets of water in the block. If you mean it was full of water , you have a problem.

Answer (score 4):

As @JPhi1618 says, if you mean 17 degrees Farenheit, then no, as the water in the block will freeze, and expand - likely causing damage to the engine, and at the very least pushing out the core plugs - it won't matter if it's one night or the whole winter, the damage will occur as soon as the water freezes.

If you mean 17 degrees Celcius, then yes, of course it's fine (but then you probably wouldn't be asking!)

Comment: It appears Cindy resides in the Michigan area, so yah, I'm thinking Fahrenheit is it.